# Swift Mapkit DistanceFromLocation Bug

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager, cllocation

As the title suggests, I am trying to find the distance between two points on a map. These points are the distance between the user and a, at this point, another location (will be an array with `for` loop and all of that good stuff when a server is introduced). But, for now, I create a new `CLLocation` and pass the default location into it. I then take the users location (which constantly updates) and then if they are further than 5 meters away, the next portion of the code can occur. Otherwise an alert comes up telling them that they are too close. Here is the code to accomplish this:

```
IBAction func ReportBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let usrLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)! , longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
    let surroundings = getLocations()
    if(usrLocation.distanceFromLocation(surroundings[0]) > 50){
        MainMap.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)

    }else{
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Whoa There!", message: "You're too close!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

And the function `getLocations` with one default location in it:

```
func getLocations() -> [CLLocation]{
    //Connect to server and all of that. 
    let myLocation : [CLLocation] = [CLLocation(latitude: -122.0312186, longitude: 37.3323314)]
    return myLocation


}
```

No matter how far away I go from the default annotation location the alert still appears. Does anybody know how/why this is happening?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Do you want them to be 5 meters away or 50 meters away?

Comment: @Paulw11 50 meters

Comment: Have you tried putting the result of `distanceFromLocation` into a variable and printing it or setting breakpoint to examine it?

Comment: Hmmm that's a good idea. I supposed I checked everything else out besides that. I'll give it a go tomorrow